# JS - Unable to return an object returned by the database (using firebase firestore)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm new to Javascript (mostly a Python person) and I'm having trouble understanding some really strange behaviors.

Long story short - I have an object in the databse (firebase firestore) that I'm trying to return. Right after I fetch it, I do a console.log and see the object in the console, and it's there! However when I return the same object...it shows as "noname" :(

Here is the code

```
function load_name() {
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var name = "noname";
    var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
    docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                name = doc.data().name;
                //following shows as 'San Francisco' in console
                console.log(name); 
                return name; //Added this line later to see if issue is fixed, but it didn't fix it.
            } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }
    ).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
    return name;
}
myname = load_name();
//^prints 'San Francisco' on console, but returns as undefined.
```

I've spent about 5 hours on this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: FYI if you want to format some code, don't just intend the first and last lines.  You can format the entire thing by using the {} button in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike python, JavaScript APIs are all asynchronous.  When you call `get()`, it returns immediately with a promise that resolves when the work is complete.  `then()` also returns a promise, and so does `catch()`.  You are returning `name` before it ever receives a value from the callback, which happens some time later.

If you want to write a function that lets the caller receive the results of some async work, you should return a promise that resolves with the results of the work, then the caller can use `then()` on that promise to listen for the results.

Basically, you are going to have to become more familiar with the conventions JavaScript uses for dealing with async work and promises.

Comment: Thanks man! This helped a lot. Finally learned about callback hell - I think i'll stick to python ;)

Comment: Node is actually a superior runtime, and the syntax gets cleaner with async/await.  (you're using old style then callbacks).  But of course you should do what's effective for you.

Comment: so do you recommend implementing a node backend?

Comment: The python runtime for Cloud Functions is currently in beta, while nodejs is fully productionized.  It also makes it easier for you to write more efficient code.  It's my preference.